# Enabling temporal variable for Image Mosaic in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms

I am working on creating a Image Mosaic to serve a set of geotiffs as a WMS. The data has temporal dimension as well.

But unfortunately however I try, I cannot succed in enabling the time variable in the dimensions tab. I followed the following tutorials.

https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/multidim/multidim/get_started/index.html#geoserver-get-started

http://www.orbital.co.ke:8080/opengeo-docs/geoserver/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html

In both of these resources, it is clearly mentioned that "you should add the following switch when launching the Java process for GeoServer."

The switches include

"-Duser.timezone=GMT"
"-Dorg.geotools.shapefile.datetime=true"

But I can't find where to put these lines of code. I tried adding these lines on the catalina.bat file like the folowing, but it did not work anyways.

`set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Duser.timezone=GMT"`
`set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dorg.geotools.shapefile.datetime=true"`

Can someone help me to find the correct place to add these java switches?

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT1:

File names are:

- 20200115T000000_geotiff_file_time
- 20200115T010000_geotiff_file_time
- 20200115T020000_geotiff_file_time
- 20200115T030000_geotiff_file_time

Contents of the mosaic_data.properties which was automatically created.

```
#-Automagically created from GeoTools-
#Fri Feb 11 11:29:42 CET 2022
ExpandToRGB=false
TypeName=snowLZWdataset
Name=snowLZWdataset
SuggestedSPI=it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi
LevelsNum=1
PathType=RELATIVE
Heterogeneous=false
Caching=false
HeterogeneousCRS=false
LocationAttribute=location
Levels=100.0,100.0
CheckAuxiliaryMetadata=false
MosaicCRS=EPSG\:32632
```

Comment: Those switches are irrelevant to your problem (they go in the catalina start up file) - you need to look at your indexer and [edit] your question to include the format of you tiff file names and the indexer.properties file. You should also include any relevant error messages from the GeoServer log

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks a lot for your response. But I did not have any indexer.properties file created. By default when I create a image mosaic store, shape files and its accompanying 5 files are created. I have updated the file names in the questions in the new edit. Should I create the indexer.properties by myself? 

And along with the shape files, another properties files is also created. I will add that along in the new edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the tutorial below, worked for me with geotiff files.

https://www.earder.com/tutorials/timeseries-with-geoserver-and-openlayers/